# Angular generic type fails when trying to AOT compile

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

I have lots of services in my app to make requests to different endpoints. They all extend a GenericService.
When GET the answer should be parsed to T or T[] so I need a T constructor inside my generic service.
Right now I'm having this

```ts
constructor(private classType: new (options?: any, ...) => T){}
...
new this.classType(item)
```

This works with JIT but when trying to AOT compile I get

```sh
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported
```

I guess the problem is the function inside de constructor but I don't know how to break that. Any suggestion?

Comment: I've found this explaining why it won't work in v2.x.x but will work in v4.x.x: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11057